# Intercepting all >= 500 error codes in a loopback application with strong-error-handler

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a simple `loopback.js` application with `strong-error-handler` https://github.com/strongloop/strong-error-handler  and the following code in `middlewares/middleware.json`

```
"final:after": {
    "./middlewares/log-error": {},
    "strong-error-handler": {
      "params": {
        "debug": false,
        "log": true
      }
    }
  }
```

My `middlewares/log-error` file is like below

```
module.exports = function createErrorLogger(options) {
    return function logError(err, req, res, next) {
      // your custom error-logging logic goes here
        console.log("inside custom error logging");
      const status = err.status || err.statusCode;
      if (status >= 500) {
        // log only Internal Server errors
        console.log('Unhandled error for request %s %s: %s',
          req.method, req.url, err.stack || err);
      }

      // Let the next error handler middleware
      // produce the HTTP response
      next(err);
    };
  }
```

I have a simple function like so

```
function myfunc(){
   myvar.asdf #myvar is undefined
}
```

In the above function `myvar` is undefined. So when I call this function 
`http://localhost:3001/myfunc` it throws this error and the app crashes

I want to avoid the app to crash. A simple `try/catch` helps to avoid this error, however is there a way to avoid the crashing of node when such an error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

### Use uncaughtException as your application won't crash and you can choose what you want to do with errors.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
})
```